# Crear ventanas XtraTabPage iguales

Tags: vb.net, vba, devexpress

Quiero crear un objeto de un `XtraTabPage` que sea igual a otro que ya tengo. Es decir: que tenga los mismos controles.
Este código me permite crear una nueva `XtraTabPage`, pero vacía:

```
Public Class Consultas
    Private Sub btnNuevaConsulta_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNuevaConsulta.Click
        Dim tabSigConsulta As New XtraTabPage
        tabSigConsulta.Text = "Consulta " & (xtpManejoConsultas.TabPages.Count + 1)
        xtpManejoConsultas.TabPages.Add(tabSigConsulta)
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: El botno crea todas las que desee pero sin controles]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Podria crear un `User Control` con el diseño que quieras reusar, entonces  agregando en cada nuevo tab este user control.

[Creating a Windows Form User Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx)

Una vez que tengas el control solo creas la instancia y la agregas a la coleccion de Controls

```
Dim uc1 As New UserControl1()
tabSigConsulta.Controls.Add(uc1)
```

de esta forma puede reutilizar un diseño en los diferentes tabs